# Multiplies every other row by 1.05

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA code that multiplies every second row by 1.05 for rows that does not have empty cells in column M and here is what I came up with (this is starting from 10)

However, it returns type mismatch error.

```
Sub MultiplyEverySecondRow()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 11 To lastRow Step 2
        Range("Q" & i & ":BC" & i).Value = Range("Q" & i & ":BC" & i).Value * 1.05
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying the values in Range `Q:BC`? Shouldn't it be `Range("M" & i ).Value = Range("M" & i).Value * 1.05`

Comment: oh that column contains tickers and actual data are in column Q to BC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array to do the manipulation and writing it back to the sheet will be much faster:

```vb
Sub MultiplyEverySecondRow()
    
    Const factor As Single = 1.05
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet    '--> adjust this to your needs
    
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rgData As Range
    Set rgData = ws.Range("Q11:BC" & lastRow)
    
    Dim arrData As Variant, iRow As Long, iColumn As Long
    arrData = rgData.Value
    
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(arrData, 1) Step 2
        For iColumn = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
           arrData(iRow, iColumn) = arrData(iRow, iColumn) * factor
        Next
    Next
    
    rgData.Value = arrData
    
End Sub
```

Furthermore you should avoid implicit referencing therefore I added the variable `ws`

Answer (score 1):

You want to multiply every cell value, not the whole range. Take a look at the following code:

```
Sub MultiplyEverySecondRow()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 11 To lastRow Step 2
        For Each c In Range("Q" & i & ":BC" & i)
            c.Value = c.Value * 1.05
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I see. I tried to mutiply the range as it took a while for my spreadsheet to multiply everything one by one in the cell. Is using the cell the only way?

Comment: @MinCho it should be, yes. You can try to set `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` to increase performance. Make sure to turn it back on after your code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

### Multiply N-th Rows

[image]

**Array**

- To loop through the elements of an array is far more efficient then looping through the cells of a range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MultiplyNthRows()
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "M11"
    Const SRC_COLUMNS As String = "Q:BC"
    Const Nth_ROW As Long = 2
    Const MULTIPLIER As Double = 1.05
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data (tickers)
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COLUMNS)
        cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    End With
    
    Dim Data()
        
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim Value, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount Step Nth_ROW
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Value = Data(r, c)
            If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                Data(r, c) = Value * MULTIPLIER
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    rg.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```

**Evaluate**

- The error is occurring because you cannot multiply an array with a number in the way you are trying to do it which is similar to how you would do it in Excel. But you can do it using `Evaluate`:

  ```
  Range("Q" & i & ":BC" & i).Value = Evaluate(Range("Q" & i & ":BC" & i).Address & "*1.05")
  ```
- Introducing a `With` statement will make it more readable:

  ```
  With Range("Q" & i & ":BC" & i)
      .Value = Evaluate(.Address & "*1.05")
  End With
  ```

---

```vb
Sub MultiplyNthRowsEvaluate()
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "M11"
    Const SRC_COLUMNS As String = "Q:BC"
    Const Nth_ROW As Long = 2
    Const MULTIPLIER As String = "1.05"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data (tickers)
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COLUMNS)
    End With
    
    Dim rrg As Range, r As Long
    
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        r = r + 1
        If r Mod Nth_ROW = 1 Then
            rrg.Value = ws.Evaluate(rrg.Address & "*" & MULTIPLIER)
        End If
    Next rrg
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so not vba, but a simple method in the sheet:

[image]

By testing if the row number is odd (using odd()) then multiply by the 1.05 stored in cell C1.